# Conemu - create a task for loading a putty session with credential

Tags: putty, login, conemu, cmder

I would like create a task on conemu for launching a putty session with autologin in order to speedup the process of connecting via ssh

Security is not an issue since most machines I need to interact are local one's (mostly raspberries or similar)

Right now I've tried the command: `putty.exe -l user -pw password host`

The autologin works but I get a console outside the conemu environment.
There is a way to launch putty in a new conemu console and pass additional credential parameter?

Comment: Versions of ConEmu and putty?

Comment: I'm working with ConEmu  v18.06.26 and Putty 0.70

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a solution

For autologin (where HostAdress could be the your session name):

```
PUTTY.EXE -cur_console -ssh <Login>@<HostAddress> -pw <Password>
```

Otherwise simply loading and existing session is:

```
PUTTY.EXE -load "session_name"
```